# COALESCE function with hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a requirement where I need to use `COALESCE` with hibernate criteria? Is there are way to implement this? I am using hibernate 5.0.

Answer (score 7):

There is an API for this in the JPA specification:
[CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce.html)

> Interface used to build coalesce expressions. A coalesce expression is
>   equivalent to a case expression that returns null if all its arguments
>   evaluate to null, and the value of its first non-null argument
>   otherwise.

As of latest hibernate versions, it is advised to use the JPQL criteria instead of the hibernate specific ones.. you would end up with something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> query = builder.createQuery(String.class);
Root<User> user= query.from(User.class);

CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce<String> coalesceExp = builder.coalesce();
coalesceExp.value(user.get("name"));
coalesceExp.value(user.get("surname"));
coalesceExp.value(user.get("middlename"));
query.select(coalesceExp);

Query q =  em.createQuery(query);
```

The bottom line is that you use the method

```
CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce<T> value(T value)
```

or

```
CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce<T> value(Expression<? extends T> value)
```

to fill your coalesc expression per your needs