# HIbernate criteria with ISNULL and calculations

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have got this query below. Just started learning criteria. Can someone help me convert it to a criteria query.

```
SELECT 
    AVAILABILITY, QUALITY, 
    (ISNULL(Act1,0) + ISNULL(Act2,0) + ISNULL(Act3,0)) 
as 'OK',
    (ISNULL(Act1,0) + ISNULL(Act2,0) + ISNULL(Act3,0)) - 
    (ISNULL(PSN,0) + ISNULL(MSN,0) + ISNULL(PPN,0) + ISNULL(MPN,0))  
 as 'Total'
 FROM ODATA where L_Code='lcode' and S_Code='scode'
```

Without the isnull part i have done like shown below with criteria.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("lCode", lCode))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("sCode", sCode));

ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("availablity").as("availablity"));
projList.add(Projections.property("quality").as("quality"));
```

Comment: Is it possible to do using criteria ?

Comment: See this question and answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064883/coalesce-function-with-hibernate-criteria